# Record Video in a Service

Tags: android

Is it possible to record video in a service, that is without setting the setPreviewDisplay?
I tried it on a HTC Desire, however it is throwing this info in the log,

MediaRecorder Prepare Failed: -1

CameraInput No surface is available for display

Is there some additional properties to be set?

Comment: I highly doubt it. You need a context (I think). You MIGHT be able to do it with passing a context into your service, but I think you have to call setPreviewDisplay. What are you trying to do? I don't think you'll be able to record video without the user knowing.

Comment: I was trying to create an surveillance kind of app which can record video in the background, BTW, it allows recording sound in the background!

Answer (score 1):

I found this snippet somewhere. Not sure if it works for media recorder, but it was working reasonably well for camera.takePicture on HTC hero android 2.1-update1 (and simulator).

```
if (camera == null) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Opening camera");
    camera = Camera.open();
}

SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(new DummyContext()); //You'll have to create your own class extending Context
camera.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
camera.startPreview();

//wait
Log.i(TAG, "Wait for cam");
    try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Woken violently");
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//take pic
Log.i(TAG, "Take pic");
camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe according to the docs

> public final void setPreviewDisplay
>   (SurfaceHolder holder)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Sets the Surface to
>   be used for live preview. **A surface is
>   necessary for preview, and preview is
>   necessary to take pictures**. The same
>   surface can be re-set without harm.

I know you are desiring to take video but, I take this to me any camera usage requires a surface.

Comment: Camera only requires a preview to start, once it is initialized i think the preview can be destroyed, I have seen IPWeb Cam using this for a MJPEG Server. I am still to figure out any apps using this for video

Answer (score 0):

> public class RecorderService extends Service {
>       private static final String TAG = "RecorderService";
>       private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
>       private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
>       private static Camera mServiceCamera;
>       private boolean mRecordingStatus;
>       private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;
>       private File filefolder;
>       private String strphoto;
>       private File photo;

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mRecordingStatus = false;
    //mServiceCamera = CameraRecorder.mCamera;
    mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
    mSurfaceView = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceView;
    mSurfaceHolder = CameraRecorder.mSurfaceHolder;

    super.onCreate();
    if (mRecordingStatus == false)
        startRecording();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopRecording();
    mRecordingStatus = false;

    super.onDestroy();
}   

public boolean startRecording(){
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //mServiceCamera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = mServiceCamera.getParameters();
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(params);
        Camera.Parameters p = mServiceCamera.getParameters();

        final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);
        Log.v(TAG, "use: width = " + mPreviewSize.width 
                    + " height = " + mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        p.setPreviewFormat(PixelFormat.YCbCr_420_SP);
        mServiceCamera.setParameters(p);

        try {
            mServiceCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
            mServiceCamera.startPreview();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mServiceCamera.unlock();

        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mServiceCamera);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
             filefolder=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Backgroundcamera/videos");
        }
        else
        {
            filefolder=RecorderService.this.getCacheDir();
        }
         if(!filefolder.exists())
            filefolder.mkdirs();
        strphoto     = System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4";
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(filefolder+"/"+strphoto);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height);
        mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder.getSurface());

        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
        mMediaRecorder.start(); 

        mRecordingStatus = true;

        return true;
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

public void stopRecording() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Recording Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    try {
        mServiceCamera.reconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();

    mServiceCamera.stopPreview();
    mMediaRecorder.release();

    mServiceCamera.release();
    mServiceCamera = null;
}
```

}
and

start the service on a click listerner.